# Post a decimal value in database using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an ASP.NET Web API project and I have a database that I am using, and the model that I am working on look something like this

```
public class PAY
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PAY_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PAY_CASH { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a simple post method look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string AddPayROW(string PAY_CODE, decimal PAY_CASH,)
{
    var PAY = new PAY()
            {
                PAY_CODE = PAY_CODE,
                PAY_CASH = PAY_CASH,
            };
    db.PAY.Add(PAY);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return "Row added successfully";
}
```

My problem is kind of weird but when I post this decimal value to the table the last number is zero

For example, if I tried to post 1.999 will be saved like this 1.990

I am using SQL Server and the datatype is `decimal(16, 3)`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are converting from a c# representation of a decimal value to a SQL Server representation of a decimal value and conversion is loosing accuracy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0

Comment: thank you but still i didn`t now what to do pleas help

Comment: It is a rounding issue and you have to decide the number of decimal places you really need.  Changing the accuracy in SQL by increasing the 3 will help.

Comment: Thank you I changed the accuracy to decimal(18,16)and when I post this value 0.123456789 saved like this 0,12000000000

Answer (score 1):

On your OnModelCreating function add this code,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PAY>().Property(x => x.PAY_CASH).HasPrecision(18,3);
```

Hope it works.

Edit : Do you have DbContext like this? For example;

```
public partial class DBO : DbContext
{
    public DBO()
        : base("ConStrEtc")
    { }
    public virtual DbSet<PAY> PAYs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PAY>().Property(x => x.PAY_CASH).HasPrecision(18, 3);
    }
}

public class PAY
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PAY_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PAY_CASH { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you but i really didn`t know where to put it pleas help i am using web api2

Comment: Inside DBContext override. I updated my answer according to your code.

Comment: And don't forget to "update-database" command after this.

Comment: Thank you very much again but didn`t work with me because I cant change the data base like this I am not working with code first .

Comment: OK, if you have database access, you can try to update that column? If you didn't set precision for "PAY_CASH" column, it has to be 18,2 for default. So you need to update it with "alter table PAY alter column PAY_CASH decimal(18,3) null" command. (According to your database of course)

Comment: i t`s already set in database to be decimal(18,3) but still saving the value the same way